# How can I use my Raspberry Pi as a CH341A Programmer(BIOS writer)?

Tags: pi-4, spi

I am trying to flash a custom BIOS to my motherboard. The motherboard's built-in software won't let me flash it because it's modded. I was told to get a CH341A Programmer to flash the modded BIOS however I was wondering if I could save some money and use my Raspberry Pi? The motherboard I'm trying to flash to is an Asus H110M-R and I have a Raspberry Pi 4B(Rev 1.2 I think)